# Is there any way to catch 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, out-of-memory, try-catch

I'm facing this problem, I'm getting 'System.OutOfMemoryException' every time I bind a very large amount of data into ASPxPivotGrid.

I would like to know is there any way that I can apply something like  to handle this exception and advice user to do something else, instead of showing the error page? Thanks.

Add: I've tried try - catch before this post. It is not working, the error page still shown.

I have a button, when I click on the button, it will fire a function to bind data into my pivotgrid.

```
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
       // codes
      catch (Exception ex)
       // message
     }

    private void BindPivotGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
       // codes
      catch (Exception ex)
       // message
     }
```

but the error page still pops out.

http://postimg.org/image/np1ylbmbx/

P/s: I apologise for my bad english :)

Regards

Comment: What stops you from adding a try..catch block, and in catch display an error pop up?

Comment: Also I have never worked with ASPxPivotGrid but I think it is an ASP.NET control. If so then please edit your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Put the your code in a try block:

```
try
{
//your code here
}
catch(Exception)
{
//put the code that executes what the user must see.
}
```

Note that catch will catch any type of exception your program encounters.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. I've added try catch block but the error page still pop up.

Answer (score 0):

What stops you from adding a try..catch block, and in catch display an error pop up? Also assuming that you are using asp.net which you have added in your subject but not as a tag.

Code will be something to the effect of the following:

**aspx.cs**

```
try
{
    //Your OutOfMemoryException code here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(yourControlId, yourControlId.GetType(), "tabs" , "jsMEthodName('"+ ex.Message +"')");
}
```

**aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function jsMEthodName(exmsg) {
    alert(exmsg);
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. I've added try catch block but the error page still pop up.

Comment: Can you show the screen-shot of the error you are receiving?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply again. The picture is attached in my question. Thanks